# getting error as deploy file not found

Tags: hardhat, alchemy

```
require('dotenv').config();
require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox');

const API_URL = process.env.API_URL;
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const API_KEY=process.env.API_KEY

console.log("API_URL:", API_URL);
console.log("PRIVATE_KEY:", PRIVATE_KEY);
console.log("API_KEY:", API_KEY);
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.18",
  networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: API_URL,
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
      alchemy: API_KEY
    },
  },
};
```

when i run npx hardhat run ./scripts/deploy.js it deploys successfully but when I run via goerli npx hardhat run ./scripts/deploy --network goerli I am getting error HH601: Script ./scripts/deploy doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I can find 2 mistakes in your attempts.

first in your hardhat.config.js it should be

```
goerli: {
  url: API_URL, //(this should contain the key already)
  accounts:PRIVATE_KEY,
},
```

secondly: it should be npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli
whereas you have: npx hardhat run ./scripts/deploy --network goerli

I hope this helps, anything just ask

Comment: Thnaks for reply now i am getting could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, error

Comment: Did you erase networks?

Comment: networks: {
        goerli: {
         url: API_URL, //(this should contain the key already)
         accounts:PRIVATE_KEY,
        },
},

Comment: no network is there

Comment: Man, I found the answer. you have to add the path inside require('dotenv').config(HERE);      For example: require("dotenv").config({ path: ".env" });

Answer (score 0):

I think that what is going on is that the goerli object has the url and the key in two separate keys. You don't have this error when you use the local hardhat node because this object never gets evaluated. Here is an example on how to put together the URL and the KEY for infura:

```
networks: {
        goerli: {
          url: `https://goerli.infura.io/v3/${API_KEY}`,
          accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
        },
},
```

Comment: Thnaks for reply now i am getting could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, error